# Return screenshot data from subprocess without residual files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a use case, where I want to take screenshots via *scrot* without leaving behind residual files:

```
"""Takes screenshots."""

from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import check_call
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

from digsigclt.os.posix.common import SCROT
from digsigclt.types import Screenshot


__all__ = ['screenshot']


JPEG = 'image/jpeg'
FORMATS = {
    'jpe': JPEG,
    'jpeg': JPEG,
    'jpg': JPEG,
    'png': 'image/png',
    'gif': 'image/gif'
}


def screenshot(filetype: str = 'jpg', display: str = ':0',
               quality: int = None, multidisp: bool = False,
               pointer: bool = False) -> Screenshot:
    """Takes a screenshot."""

    try:
        content_type = FORMATS[filetype]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('Invalid image file type.') from None

    command = [SCROT, '--silent', '--display', display]

    if quality is not None:
        command += ['--quality', str(quality)]

    if multidisp:
        command.append('--multidisp')

    if pointer:
        command.append('--pointer')

    with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpd:
        tmpfile = Path(tmpd).joinpath(f'digsigclt-screenshot.{filetype}')
        command.append(str(tmpfile))
        check_call(command)

        with tmpfile.open('rb') as file:
            return Screenshot(file.read(), content_type)
```

The code works as intended. What bothers me, however, is the workaround that I had to take using `TemporaryDirectory`. All tests using a `ǸamedTemporaryFile` directly failed due to the fact, that python opens the target file before the subprocess writes to it, so that a subsequent `read()` would return an empty bytes object.
Is there a way to improve the intermediate file handling without the `TemporaryDirectory` workaround and without opening and closing the intermediate file more than once?

Comment: The problem is that `scrot` silently doesn't write to an existing file, not that you can't read the contents. You could just run it in the temporary directory and do `-e 'echo $n'` to get the file it wrote to ... or you keep doing what you are doing right now. Consider just generating a random filename in `/tmp` though, that's probably easier. Or you know, use a different tool or even a Python library for the screenshot if you really want to avoid the temporary files altogether.

Comment: Aaah. Thanks for the hint. I just realized that scrot has the `--overwrite` option for that. I think my solution lies there.